# Does Android NDK support native method(OMXAL) of video encoding?

Tags: android-ndk, android-mediacodec, openmax

In android-NDK-r9c, Google provide a sample 'native-media'. In this sample, we can use OMXAL in the C level to do the MeidaPlayer job.

I am wondering if we can do media encoding this way? I tried to write the corresponding functions, but I failed, and according to the errors report, there is no such function defined in the local libs.

Does anyone know anything about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, android NDK doesn't support the API to omx encode now, although it provides the omx decode, one can find the google sample in the NDK sample 'jni-media'. If we want to use the omx encode, we must have the code provided by the hardware company. Here is a helpful [link](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdevnet-forums/multimedia-optimization-qdsp/12520)

Answer (score 2):

NDK r10 comes with native lib to work with MediaCodec.